# Constant disk size on GeoGraphics Image

Tags: graphics, geographics

I would like to know how to generate a constant disk size on a GeoGraphics image. Currently my code is something like this:

```
Module[
    {(* Module Inputs *)
    circleRadius = Quantity[15, "NauticalMiles"],
    },
    (* Module function that uses those inputs *)
    GeoGraphics[{
        Thickness[.003],
        Red,
        GeoPath[{GeoPosition[{38.884724, -74.422294}], GeoPosition[{35.192252, -74.922013}], GeoPosition[{26.763382, -77.037353}]}],
        Darker[Cyan],
        GeoPath[{GeoPosition[city1], GeoPosition[{38.884724,  -74.422294}]}],
        GeoPath[{GeoPosition[city2], GeoPosition[{26.763382,  -77.037353}]}],
        Black,
        Disk[GeoPosition[city1], .25],
        Disk[GeoPosition[city2], .25],
        FaceForm[Darker[Gray]],
        (* Code that plots Polygon[]'s of each continent *)
        },
    GeoBackground -> None,
    ImageSize -> {1000, 1000},
    GeoCenter -> GeoPosition[city2],
    GeoRange -> {{20., 45.}, {-85., -65.}},
    GeoProjection -> "Equirectangular"
    ]
]
```

The module input circleRadius isn't used but I've tried using GeoDisk using that as the radius, however regardless of what settings I put it shows opaque on the map and I want a solid black disk. The problems I'm having using just the `Disk[]` function is that between different maps it gets resized when the only setting I change is `GeoRange` to focus on a different coordinate range as shown below.

Small disk:

[image: small disk]

Larger disk size:

[image: large disk]

My question is: Is there a way to set the disk/line thicknesses to be sized the same between maps? Or alternatively is there a way to have `GeoDisk` show as fully visible instead of the transparent color that shows up?

This is what I mean by not fully visible:

[image: Both GeoDisk and Disk]

Or is this entirely not possible and I should fiddle with the `.25` Disk size until they appear more or less the same size between maps?

Thanks in advance for any help!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> ***... is there a way to have GeoDisk show as fully visible instead of the transparent color?***

```
GeoGraphics[{Red, GeoDisk[{25, -40}, Quantity[2000, "Kilometers"]]}, 
 GeoRange -> "World", Frame -> True]
```

[image]

Wrap the styling directives with `GeoStyling`:

```
GeoGraphics[{GeoStyling[Red], GeoDisk[{25, -40}, Quantity[2000, "Kilometers"]]}, 
 GeoRange -> "World", Frame -> True]
```

[image]